# Select a value using iif access query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a row who contains this value :

```
account :
adm.ahrgrst001
adm.ns2dhdujhd
adm.ff2hdjhh
adm.haidhidh103
adm.hshiksh122
adm.cn3ehuioe
```

i want to extract two different values:
when it ends like  `adm.hshiksh122` i want to extract  `hshiksh`
and with start with `adm.cn3ehuioe` i want `ehuioe`
both without the `adm.` at the beginning

I have thinked this

```
IIF(isnumeric(RIGHT (account,3)),LEFT(account,LEN(account)-4),RIGHT (account,LEN(account)-7))
```

the value that are like `adm.cn3ehuioe` i got wrong like `adm.cn3ehui`
and  `adm.ahrgrst001` is correct `ahrgrst`

Thanks to everyone who will read

Comment: MS Access or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS, and only a single version (2007 OR 2010) unless you have a specific multi-version requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry it's MS access

Comment: Then please correct your tags.

Comment: Do you want values that end with 001 or values that end with 3 digits? And what do you want to do with them? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: i would like to get ff1jdsfkdhf  from adm.ff1jdsfkdhf' and ahrgrst  'adm.ahrgrst001' .
sorry for bad explanation

Comment: This is different from what you say in your question. Read carefully what you have written there. Also why the single quotes? Are they also included in the values? Post sample data in text tabular format and expected results in text tabular format.

Comment: Thanks for the observation I edit the post in the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to get the 2 types of values is with:

```
account LIKE 'adm.[!0-9][!0-9]#[!0-9]*'
```

for the values that have 2 letters, 1 digit and letters after the dot, and:

```
account LIKE 'adm.*###'
```

for the values that end in 3 digits.

So use this:

```
SELECT IIF(
  account LIKE 'adm.*###' ,
  MID(account, 5, LEN(account) - 7),
  MID(account, 8)
) AS result
FROM tablename
WHERE account LIKE 'adm.*###' OR account LIKE 'adm.[!0-9][!0-9]#[!0-9]*'
```

If there are no other values than these 2 types then you may remove the `WHERE` clause.

Results for your sample data:

| result |
| --- |
| ahrgrst |
| dhdujhd |
| hdjhh |
| haidhidh |
| hshiksh |
| ehuioe |

Comment: Thank you so much , you saved me two times today

Comment: @prider fine if it worked. Also I provided a simpler solution to your previous question.

Comment: Thank you so much @forpas , you helped me so much